# Why getting NoClassDefFound for class that is in jar in lib folder?

Tags: java

Using Tomcat7, I load a Jasper class via urlClassLoader and when I call the constructor, I get a throwable NoClassDefFoundError complaining that it can't find an apache/poi class that it should have been able to find in the project WEB-INF/lib, since the poi jar is in that folder.

Why isn't it automatically searching and loading the class from the tomcat lib folder?

```
Class<?> JRXlsExporter = urlClassLoader.loadClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter");
Constructor constructor = JRXlsExporter.getConstructor();        // throws  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet
```

Comment: Where are you exactly adding the apache poi jar?

Comment: Is the _Jasper_ JAR also in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder?

Comment: Yes the jasper jar is also in WEB-INF/lib, and that constructor there has a dependency on the poi jar also in the same folder.  The reason I am loading this jar with a classloader is because it seems to be the only way to guarantee that I will load this version of the jasper jar, since there is an older version in the tomcat lib folder that I can't be removed

Comment: Just a guess, but try using the [`-Xbootclasspath/p:path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) option and replace `path` with the path to your _Jasper_ JAR. If you can't modify the command used to launch _Tomcat_ then maybe try using the [`JAVA_OPTS`](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tomcat-the-definitive/9780596101060/ch01s02.html) environment variable.

Comment: @Abra  those options would impact all projects using that tomcat instance, and unfortunately I can change config options for only this project since other projects (using the same tomcat instance) rely on the older jasper JAR,  I would love to find a configuration solution rather than code to load classes in via a classloader

Comment: Another suggestion: add the URL for POI to the list of URLs when you create `urlClassLoader`

Comment: But then I would have to go through the same tedious code changes to load the poi classes, right?  I'm wondering why the classes aren't automatically loaded

Comment: Class loaders defer to their parent class loader. How did you create your `URLClassLoader`? Did you give it a parent? How is it related to the class loader that loads the POI classes? Maybe you should investigate how class loaders work.